# Systematic way to create Matrix with given minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

Suppose you're given a minimal polynomial, is there an efficient and systematic (!) way to find a matrix with given minimal polynomial?

For example for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ find an $n \times n$-Matrix such that its minimal polynomial is $(X - 1)^k$ for a given $1 \leq k \leq n$.

Say we even limit ourselves to $n=5$ and $k=4$, is there a better way to find such a Matrix without using just trial and error?

Comment: I just recently learned about the companion matrix but would it also work if the minimal polynomial isn't of degree n?

Comment: Google "companion matrix"

Comment: I think I know how a companion matrix works but how would a $5 \times 5$ companion matrix look for the polynomial $p(X) := (X-1)^4 = X^4 - 4X^3 + 6X^2 - 4X + 1$? In our lecture and on Wikipedia it's only defined if we have a polynomial of the form $X^5 + a_4 X^4 + ... + a_0$ which $p(X)$ doesn't fulfill. What am I missing?

Comment: If the polynomial is factored, use Jordan form. For $(X-1)^4$ in a $5x5$, put five $1$'s on the main diagonal, and then three $1$'s just above those in locations (2,1), (3,2) and (4,3), with $0$'s everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a matrix $M$ such that $(M-I)^k=0$, then
$$
             M=I+N
$$
where $N$ satisfies $N^k=0$. One such $N$ is a $k\times k$ block matrix
$$
   \left[\begin{array}{k,k}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
       \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{array}\right]
$$
You can generalize this idea through Jordan Canonical Form.